# How to enable pop up in Web View?

Tags: reactjs, uiwebview, wkwebview, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

Currently using `"react-native-webview": "^6.11.1"` in application. While loading a website, there's a pop up which need to be approved. How can I enable/allow webview to display the pop up?

**Tried on a few things:**

1. Setting prop `useWebKit` to TRUE (WkWebview) and FALSE (UIWebview)
2. Setting prop `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` to return true for every URL

To be more specific, the **pop I mentioned looks like below** when you run it on Desktop Chrome. There should be one pop up blocker notification requesting you to allow pop up. 
[image]

Comment: I'm suppose the direction of this is towards "createWebViewWithConfiguration" from WKWebView, this method suppose to trigger by `window.open()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Append the following code in `RNCWKWebView.m` under method `didMoveToWindow`

```
wkWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;
wkWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;
```

Btw, im using WKWebView.

---

**Explanation**

They key here is **javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically** which is actually set to NO as default value for iOS according to [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkpreferences/1536573-javascriptcanopenwindowsautomati?language=objc)

> The default value is NO in iOS and YES in macOS.

Setting the this value to YES, indicates whether JavaScript can open windows without user interaction. In this case, I'm tackling with the `window.open()` function from my website's javascript.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me on **Android** and **IOS**

**javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true,**

```
 <WebView
     javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically=true,
     source={{ uri: URL }}
      />
```